# Close modal by clicking on background, but not on content

Tags: jquery, video, modal-dialog

I have a modal that fadesIn and displays a video.

I'd like to click the modal's background color (which fills the screen 100%x100%) to close the modal. The problem is, the way I have it coded at the moment, if I click the video player controls, it closes the modal as well.

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/PWGHH/

Thanks.

Comment: Yea, the website imposes a timer on me limiting how soon I can accept. It just ended. Accepted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#commercial1').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks so much. I'm not familiar with that bit of jQuery. Thanks for enlightening me.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for you is to separate the 100% div from the video object but and make the fae effect on them both and make the click event on the v100% div.